# Enzyme simulate the onChange event of child component

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I'm using enzyme  and jest to test my React app and now I'm trying to trigger "onChange" in child component.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    
    state = {
        active: null
    };

    handleChange = panel => (event, active) => {
        this.setState({
            active: (active ? tabs : null)
        });
    };

    render() {
        const { colors, tabs } = this.props;
        const { active } = this.state;

        return (
            <div className={colors.black}>
                { panes.map( ( { left, right } , key ) => 
                    <ChildComponent key={key} expanded={active === key} onChange={this.handleChange(key)}>
                        <ChildComponentLeft />}>{left}</ChildComponentLeft>
                        <ChildComponentRight>{right}</ChildComponentRight>
                    </ChildComponent> 
) 
                }
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default withStyles(styles)(MyComponent);
```

How can i test this "onChange" ?

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```js
wrapper.find('ChildComponent').simulate('change', {
  target: { /* whatever */ },
});
```

(if you have more than one `ChildComponent`, stick a `.at()` call just after the `.find()`)

Make sure you force a repaint via [`wrapper.update`](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/update.html) after the `change` event to ensure your component gets re-rendered.

Comment: I do have more than one but when I try with  wrapper.find(ChildComponent ).last().simulate('change', {
            target: { key:0 }, 
        });  my handleChange is not triggerd  and what did you mean by "force a repaint after the change"

Comment: I updated the answer to include details about the repaint.

Comment: While having functions that return functions is not unusual, I don't see it used that often in event handlers for React components. Can you explain what `ChildComponent`, `tabs`, and `active` are supposed to be doing, and how you want to see `onChange` function? Remember that you may have a lot more context into your problem than what you have posted. :)